# Enhancing anti-tracking measures

Tags: safari, privacy, proxy, facebook

Recently, Facebook introduced a “feature” that makes any link to a Wordpress blog fail.  I found a [way to reverse those effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68154824/rewrite-rules-to-suppress-more-than-one-tracking-parameter) for my own blog, but it would be cool to do the same if I were to click such an altered link in Facebook or Google.

**Can any of the following be done, and if so, how?**

One way (if possible) would be to have JavaScript (or any other language) that runs on page load to check and possibly rewrite links in the page.  Not one embedded in the page but applied by the browser to any incoming page.

Another would be a way to tell the browser to pass every http(s) through such a function.

Do the conversion in a proxy or firewall on anything going out on ports 80 or 443.  Or is that coming in?

Bonus if I can do it on an iPhone or iPad!

Answer (score 0):

A **partial** answer, would be a proxy or firewall that can do something *like* this (Javascript, but another language would be acceptable):

```
var address = new URL( ??? );
// the URI requested when someone clicks a link on a client of the proxy

address.searchParams.delete(utm_source);
address.searchParams.delete(utm_medium);
address.searchParams.delete(utm_campaign);
address.searchParams.delete(utm_term);
address.searchParams.delete(utm_content);
address.searchParams.delete(gclid);
address.searchParams.delete(fbclid);
address.searchParams.delete(dclid);
address.searchParams.delete(gclsrc);

// send the cleaned up request to the server
return address.some?method;  
// OR
??? = new something(address);
// OR
??? = new something(address.toString);
```

Comment: Discovered a Safari extension that claims to do this and more, but Safari refuses to install it.   And I have no clue how to make XCode build it.
https://github.com/Sh1d0w/clean-links

Comment: I did get clean links installed and enabled as an extension.  But it isn't working.  The links still go to Facebook's tracking script before being redirected to the intended location.  And the fbclid is still there afterward.